# is there a modulation in boogie-woogie?

Tags: theory, blues

Consider the standard boogie-woogie bass such as [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aTypical_boogie_woogie_bass.png). The C, F and G phrases are each in its own mixolydian. Is that a modulation from C to F and G?
If no, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The F and G are heard as the subdominant and dominant of the home key.  When listening you have the sense of being away from the C chord and wanting to return to it.  A modulation sets up a new home key.  It can be temporary (like a vacation home) or permanent (like moving to a new home, for instance the modulation just before the last chorus of "Grandma Got Run Over By A Reindeer").

Comment: You get a vote up for reminding me about them being heard as D and S. I see wikipedia article on modulation refers to [Tonicization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonicization) as a kind of "smaller" modulation, where the original tonic is still present. Is it a tonicization then?

Comment: I don't think so, because you don't get the sense that you want to rest on F or G. Using an arrow -> to indicate that a chord "pushes" toward another one and a comma to indicate a restful chord, the blues is heard as C, F -> C, G -> C or C, F -> C, F -> G -> C. Tonicization would be C, D7 -> G, G7 -> C. Modulation: C -> F -> G7 -> C, F -> G7 -> C, G -> A7 -> D. (That's a "truck driver's gear change"; see www.gearchange.org.)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could consider it a modulation; but it's normally considered part of the "changes".

It's as if C-mixolydian, F-mixolydian and G-mixolydian were all superposed together to create a C-"blues" scale. C-D-**Eb**-E-F-G-A-Bb-**B**-C. The notes that belong to the "superscale" but not the "current" scale are the **blue notes**.

But the "full" blues scale is constructed by using the dorian scales: C-dorian, F-dorian and G-dorian, giving: C-D-**Eb**-E-F-**F#**-G-**Ab**-A-Bb-**B**-C. This gives you *more* **blue notes** against the mixolydian harmony.

Comment: You get a vote up for explaining the merge of scales. Somehow your and Mark's answers together give almost the complete picture. Except I think I need a reference to an explanation of mode progressions in the super-scales as opposed to chord progressions in the scales. Could it be explained in the books on *jazz* harmony?

Comment: It would *have to* be in a book on Jazz harmony; although I've never read one. Historically, I think, Jazz developed out of Blues; like a creole language from a pidgin language.

Comment: Now that you mention it, the dorian construction is probably a Jazz *revision*; the origin of the blues scale was probably based on minor pentatonic.

Comment: Rats! That doesn't work either! **I don't know where the F#/Gb comes from!** Ascending Melodic Minor?   it just kinda *shows up.*